# Undefined reference to QLocalSocket::QLocalSocket(QObject*)

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qlocalsocket

I am trying to use QLocalSocket in QT, but I have the error `Undefined Reference to QLocalSocket::QLocalSocket(QObject*)`

Here is the beginning of the .cpp :

```
#include "client.h"

Client::Client(QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent),
  m_socket(new QLocalSocket(this))
{
   tryConnection();
}
```

And the beginning of the .h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalSocket>

class Client : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Client(QObject *parent = 0);
  ~Client();
```

I work with QT 5.8 on linux.

Comment: Are you linking against the `QtNetwork` library?

Comment: I tried to include <QLocalSocket> but I had an error, so I include <QNetwork/QLocalSocket>

Comment: I'm talking about *linking*, not *header inclusion.* Are you using QMake? If so, can you post the `.pro` file?

Comment: @Angew Oh yes sorry. It was the error, I forgot to link network. Is it ok now. Thanks